# Listing the folders(of format "run_dd_mm_yy") of last 7 days

Tags: linux

I have a directory which contains folders in the format "run_dd_mm_yy" . These folders contain sub folders. But i need to list only the folders(of above format) of last seven days . Can u suggest me any commands in linux to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell command

```
date -d '1 day ago' +'run_%d_%m_%y'
```

Will give you the folder names based on todays date but a number of days ago

```
for d in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; do datestr=`date -d "$d day ago" +'run_%d_%m_%y'`; ls -l $datestr;done
```

Does a top level listing of the folders for the last 7 days

If you need to get the subfolders at the top level of each folder instead of `ls -l $datestr` use something like

```
find $datestr -type d -maxdepth 1 -print
```

Comment: I already answered that question, as shown above use ``find`` with ``type d and -maxdepth 1``.  See ``man find`` for a discussion of how the options for find work